# Перенос значений из массива в таблицу React

Tags: reactjs

Всем привет, помогите пожалуйста с перенос данных из массива в таблицу по циклу.

```
const Products = [
  {
    name: "one",
   count: "1"
  },
  {
    name: "two",
   count: "1"
  }]
```

Этот массив надо по циклу перенести сюда

```
function Tables (props) {
    const 
    return (
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                Product
                </td>
                <td>
                Count
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                
            </tr>
        </table>
    )
}
```

Product и Count - хедер у таблицы, эти значения трогать не надо, а вот в остальные tr надо занести значения из массива.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function Tables (props) {
  const Products = [
    {
      name: "one",
     count: "1"
    },
    {
      name: "two",
     count: "1"
    }
  ]
  
  return (
      <table>
          <tr>
              <td>
              Product
              </td>
              <td>
              Count
              </td>
          </tr>
          {Products.map((item,i)=><tr key={i}>
              <td>{item.name}</td>
              <td>{item.count}</td>
          </tr>
          )}
      </table>
  )
}
```

Comment: `key` забыли..)

Comment: не принципиально, тут статические данные)